# Make Webpack DevServer write to disk in development environment with `create-react-app`'s

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, webpack-dev-server

I have a project that was created with `create-react-app` and has been "ejected". For my use-case, I need to update the Webpack config to output files to the `./build` directory in the development environment, like it does in production.

I added a `devServer` property to my config:

```js
devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
}
```

and I updated the `output` property to have a `path` in the development environment:

```js
// I changed this:
output: {
    path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
    ...
}

// To this:
output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    ...
}
```

When I run `yarn start`, no files are written to the `build` directory.

What should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `create-react-app` doesn't setup `webpack-dev-server` using the `devServer` property of `config/webpack.config.js`.

Instead, it uses the `webpack-dev-server` directly in `scripts/start.js` with the following code:

```js
const createDevServerConfig = require("../config/webpackDevServer.config");

// ...

const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
    proxyConfig,
    urls.lanUrlForConfig
);
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
// Launch WebpackDevServer.
devServer.listen(port, HOST, (err) => {
    // ...
}
```

In other words, to alter the behavior of the DevServer, you should be updating `config/webpackDevServer.config` instead of setting the `devServer` property in `config/webpack.config.js`.

In this case, I just needed to add the `writeToDisk` property:

```js
module.exports = function (proxy, allowedHost) {
    return {
        writeToDisk: true,
        //...
    }
}
```

This will cause the output files to be written to `./dist` by default. To set a different directory, it is still necessary to also update `output.path` in `config/webpack.config.js`:

```js
output: {
    path: paths.appBuild,
    ...
}
```